# Replace DataFrame rows with missing string values with the row mean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe as follow. Column `"b"` of the DataFrame has string value with maximum of 5 numbers. So, I want to consider the missing values in the rows which they has less than 5 numbers. For example, the second rows has 2 numbers, I fill the row with mean of 4 and 6. And also for the third row, I want the same thing.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [ 1,  2, 3 ]
df['b'] = [ '2, 3, 4, 5,6' , '4,6', '  6,8']
```

[image: The data frame which I have]

I here is the DataFrame which I want.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach:

Splitting on comma and expanding creates a DataFrame; then `mask` the rows with NaN values and fill them with the mean:

```
tmp = df['b'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(float)
df[[f'b{i}' for i in range(1,tmp.shape[1]+1)]] = (tmp.mask(tmp.isna().any(axis=1))
                                                  .T.fillna(tmp.mean(axis=1)).T
                                                  .astype(int))
df = df.drop(columns='b')
```

Output:

```
   a  b1  b2  b3  b4  b5
0  1   2   3   4   5   6
1  2   5   5   5   5   5
2  3   7   7   7   7   7
```

Answer (score 0):

we apply `eval` to column b, replace short tuples with tuples of size 5 filled with averages, expand into columns and rename columns

```
df2 = (df['b'].apply(eval)
              .apply(lambda t: t if len(t)==5 else (sum(t)/len(t),)*5)
              .apply(pd.Series)
              .rename(columns = lambda n:f'b{n+1}')
    )
```

we then join it to the original column a

```
df[['a']].join(df2)
```

output:

```
    a   b1  b2  b3  b4  b5
0   1   2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
1   2   5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0 5.0
2   3   7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0 7.0
```

Comment: Thanks @piterbarg. works for me also. However, I accept the first true answer.